# Python Pandas Writing Value to a Specific Row & Column in the data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I have a Pandas df of Stock Tickers with specific dates,  I want to add the adjusted close for that date using yahoo finance.  I iterate through the dataframe, do the yahoo call for that Ticker and Date, and the correct information is returned.  However, I am not able to add that information back to the original df.  I have tried various loc, iloc, and join methods, and none of them are working for me.  The df shows the initialized zero values instead of the new value.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import timedelta

# Build the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker':['BGFV','META','WIRE','UG'], 
                   'Date':['5/18/2021','5/18/2021','4/12/2022','6/3/2019'],
                   })

# Change the Date to Datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# initialize the adjusted close
df['Adj_Close'] = 0.00 # You'll get a column of all 0s

# iterate through the rows of the df and retrieve the Adjusted Close from Yahoo
for i in range(len(df)):
  ticker = df.iloc[i]['Ticker']
  start = df.iloc[i]['Date']
  end = start + timedelta(days=1)

  # YF call
  data = yf.download(ticker, start=start, end=end)

  # Get just the adjusted close
  adj_close = data['Adj Close']

  # Write the acjusted close to the dataframe on the correct row
  df.iloc[i]['Adj_Close'] = adj_close

  print(f'i value is {i} and adjusted close value is {adj_close} \n')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do is to use `loc` as below-

```
# change this line
  df.loc[i,'Adj_Close'] =   adj_close.values[0]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you for the help.  I will have to look at adj_close.values[0] more closely to see what that is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def get_adj_close(x):
    # You needn't specify end param because period is already set to 1 day
    df = df = yf.download(x['Ticker'], start=x['Date'], progress=False)
    return df['Adj Close'][0].squeeze()

df['Adj_Close'] = df.apply(get_adj_close, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Ticker       Date   Adj_Close
0   BGFV 2021-05-18   27.808811
1   META 2021-05-18  315.459991
2   WIRE 2022-04-12  104.320045
3     UG 2019-06-03   16.746983
```